# Is there a CSS property to define selection overflow?

Tags: javascript, html, css

When you select text in a `textarea`, the visible overlay of the selection is contained within the `textarea`, like this:

[image: Selection contained in element]

When you select text on "regular" elements, like a simple `div`, you get this:

[image: Overflowing selection]

The visible selection overflows the element. Is there a CSS property or any other way to keep the selection visibly contained within the HTML element?

Answer (score 3):

You can add

```
overflow:hidden;
```

to the div.

[Demo](http://jsbin.com/solaleyeve/edit?html,output).

Comment: Also worth noting that this *issue* is related to Webkit. I'd simply leave it like it is ;)

Comment: @Roko No, Safari has exactly the same problem. Also, this just looks pretty!

Comment: @nicael than let's say that Webkit is bat at highlighting.

Comment: here i am not using overflow, but i am using display:inline-block;

there was no need to add overflow, it got to be something related to the natural behaviour of div.

Comment: Any way I think browsers should highlight exactly like Mozilla does... and that's context within an element, not imaginary line-height space outside of the actual box model...

Comment: @nicael overflow: hidden hides everything outside the content box, both elements and other things like selections.

Comment: ah, got it, it is because of the div property.
By default div comes with the css "display:block;" which takes up the entire the width.

the moment we add inline-block it only takes the width specified in our css, and not the extra spaces.

Not a clear explaination i know. but, you guys are getting right?